# geom_tile do not present true colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with ggplot2 in R using geom_tile with the following data:

```
structure(list(Taxonomy = c("f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-1", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-2", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-3", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-4", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-5", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-6", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-7", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-8", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-9", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-10", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-11", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-12", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-13", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-14", "f__Eggerthellaceae g__Enterorhabdus", 
"f__Eggerthellaceae g__Enterorhabdus-1", "f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio", 
"f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio-1", "f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas", 
"f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas-1", "f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia", 
"f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia-1", "f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1-1", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-1", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-2", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-3", "f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Candidatus_Arthromitus", "f__Oscillospiraceae g__", 
"f__Ruminococcaceae g__Paludicola", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Blautia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Blautia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-4", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-5", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-6", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__GCA-900066575", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__A2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-4"
), ICI = c(1.270207852194, 0.939759036144578, 1.08761904761905, 
0.9, 0.727611940298507, 0.883895131086142, 0.70253164556962, 
1.45454545454545, 1.0327868852459, 0.760598503740648, 1.3495145631068, 
1.27551020408163, 1.73170731707317, 1.77027027027027, 0.973867595818815, 
0.81981981981982, 0.945454545454546, 18, 0.652707275803723, 0.575313807531381, 
0.947368421052632, 2.52380952380952, 1.11811023622047, 1.30864197530864, 
2.4078431372549, 2.72727272727273, 1.02564102564103, 0.658536585365854, 
0.926829268292683, 0.833333333333333, 0.18705035971223, 12.2, 
10, 1, 1.56910569105691, 5.25, 0.918032786885246, 0.857142857142857, 
1, 1.94444444444444, 1.85365853658537, 0.471698113207547, 14, 
1.22222222222222, 4.95, 1.38983050847458, 13, 0.977777777777778, 
1.72727272727273, 2.5, 1.25, 1.47540983606557, 0.7, 1.06666666666667, 
0.909090909090909, 1.12903225806452, 0.846153846153846, 0.806201550387597, 
95, 0.694117647058824, 0.970588235294118, 0.836842105263158, 
1.06507592190889, 0.39344262295082, 0.976744186046512, 1.25196850393701, 
1.28333333333333, 0.790960451977401, 0.7, 1.21995332555426), 
    Sample_ID = c(" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70"), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to create one column "heatmap" using this code:

```
brks = c(0, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100)
g <- ggplot(data = ici_table, aes(x=Sample_ID, y=Taxonomy, fill=ICI)) + 
  geom_tile(width=0.08, height=0.95) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("black", "steelblue4",
                                "steelblue3", "steelblue2", "steelblue",
                                "yellow2", "yellow1", "yellow"),
                       limits=c(0,100),
                       breaks=brks, labels=brks) + 
  labs(x="ICI", y="") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="right",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin= unit(c(1,1,1,-0.1), "cm"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())

g
```

But surprisingly, the colors do not match the true values (i.e., I cannot find a yellow square for the ICI = 95 in my data).

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: sorry @Almog I re-read your question and seems to me like you're absolutely aware of the 95 value being an outlier and **want that reflected** in the visualization. I explored your data and notice the problem (require aggregation prior to plotting) - can you see if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, indeed I want to use the 95 value. What do you mean by aggregation?

Comment: I summarize the real culprit in my latest answer is in the TLDR section :) The value of 95 is on `f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3` (row 59), but it isn't the only row. There are 4 rows of `f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3` with 4 different `ICI` values. Because you didn't aggregate, the last value was used (0.975, row 65 instead of 95.000, row 59),  look at my latest answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR

There are a few problems that causes the `fill` color to concentrate around the "black" end of the color spectrum, but upon further inspection, the real culprit is the fact that there are multiple repeating values for each value of `Taxonomy` in the visualization, and so your value of 95 (row 59) is most likely overwritten by the later value (row 65) since it's the same `Taxonomy`. This explains why you felt that 'geom_tile do not present true colors', as per your question title.

One would think the biggest offender is that massive outlier you have within the `ICI` column, hence squashing all the other values to a very small range. This can be verified:

```
summary(ici_table$ICI)
```

Outputs:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1870  0.8489  1.0489  3.4674  1.5457 95.0000
```

> But surprisingly, the colors do not match the true values (i.e., I
> cannot find a yellow square for the ICI = 95 in my data).

As I've pointed out in the TLDR, you're also not really going to see a yellow square corresponding the exact value of ICI = 95 (row 59) on your visualization because it belongs to the `f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3` taxonomy, and that isn't the only observed value for this taxonomy. So `ggplot` will, reasonably, use the later value it find for `f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3`, which happens to be row 65.

[image]

As a verification, plotting the last 15 rows of the dataframe you're getting less than 15 values in your visualization:

```
ggplot(data = tail(ici_table, 15), aes(x=Sample_ID, y=Taxonomy, fill=ICI)) + ...
```

To reiterate, you will not find 15 squares / grids, corresponding to the 15 rows (`tail(ici_table, 15)`). So herein lies **the main problem**: you need to aggregate the values, by say the `sum` or the `mean` before visualizing their values on the heatmap.

In other words, since you likely want to plot a heatmap using aggregate values (sum of values for all observations in each `Taxonomy`), you should perform the aggregation prior to plotting the heatmap.

### Solution

The following code visualizes the average value of `AVGICI` grouped by `Taxonomy`:

```
library(dplyr)
ici_table %>% 
  tail(15) %>% 
  group_by(Taxonomy, Sample_ID) %>% 
  summarise(AvgICI = mean(ICI)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sample_ID, y=Taxonomy, fill=AvgICI)) + 
  geom_tile(width=0.08, height=0.95) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("black", "steelblue4",
                                "steelblue3", "steelblue2", "steelblue",
                                "yellow2", "yellow1", "yellow"),
                       limits=c(0,100)
                       )
```

And this time you absolutely see the big outlier group (`f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3`) since their average value is 47.988 compared to the 0 to 1.3 range for values in other groups.

You may also set `sum` instead of `mean` to be the aggregation function and observe the differences.

```
brks <-  c(0, 10, 25, 50, 75)
library(dplyr)
ici_table %>% 
  group_by(Taxonomy, Sample_ID) %>% 
  summarise(AvgICI = mean(ICI)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sample_ID, y=Taxonomy, fill=AvgICI)) + 
  geom_tile(width=0.08, height=0.95) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("black", "steelblue4",
                                "steelblue3", "steelblue2", "steelblue",
                                "yellow2", "yellow1", "yellow"),
                       limits=c(0,100),
                       breaks=brks, 
                       labels=brks
                       ) +
  labs(x="ICI (Average)", y="") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="right",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin= unit(c(1,1,1,-0.1), "cm"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Along with your themes, you can still clearly find the outlier group. Note that due to the values being squashed to nearly the minimum limit, most of the bars will be approximately black:

[image]